# Error: Connection not secure, with the flag --ignore-certificate-errors, Python Selenium Proxy

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a program in Python (3.11) using Selenium (4.11.2) that should access the chat gpt website, ask questions, and receive answers. I am using a proxy through SeleniumWire. For some reason, every time I try to access any website on the internet, I encounter a "Connection not secure" error (I have Chrome 114.0.5735.134 installed), and I am using Undetected Chrome.

I can't seem to remove this window. I've tried different proxies, added the --ignore-certificate-errors flag to the options, and everything is incorrect – all proxies are using the HTTPS protocol. Nevertheless, the certificate problem persists. This error doesn't appear in Firefox, but I specifically need to use Undetected Chrome. If you know what to do, please help me.
Below is my code:

```
#from selenium import webdriver
import time
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from seleniumwire import webdriver
import pickle
from seleniumwire import undetected_chromedriver as uc


#proxy
proxy_options = {
    'proxy': {
        #'http': f'http://dronlexelon:6mGggY8SjR@23.27.3.242:50100',
        'https': f'https://dronlexelon:6mGggY8SjR@23.27.3.242:50100',
        'no_proxy': "localhost,127.0.0.1"
    }
}

#webdriver
options = Options()
browser = uc.Chrome(
    options=options,
    seleniumwire_options=proxy_options
)

#options argument
#options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\roman\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\\User Data\Default')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("--window-size=1366,768")
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36')
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--password-store=basic")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--enable-automation")
options.add_argument("--disable-browser-side-navigation")
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-software-rasterizer")
options.add_argument('--disable-logging')
options.add_argument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")

#
browser.get("https://2ip.ru")
time.sleep(50)
pickle.dump(browser.get_cookies(), open("session", "wb"))
```

I've tried various proxies, added configuration flags, but nothing helps, except for using a different browser. However, I specifically need Undetected Chrome. So if you know a solution, please respond.